# Post data to a form on another server and pops up a window

Tags: post

I am looking input for the scenario, where in server1 open the populated data in a form from another server in  a new window without you using the activeX and serverside scripting.

How we can do it?
Thanks

Comment: I am so sorry, if that did not communicate properly  let me try to another time to explain. here is the case.  I need to post the data which can contain multiple key value to some other server, for their form to be pre poplulated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too sure I understand the question completely, but you can POST to a website using python's urllib or urllib2 modules:

```
import urllib
import urllib2

opener = urllib2.build_opener(MultipartPostHandler)
opts = {
'field_name' = value,
'another_field_name' = another_value,
}

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.0; en-GB; rv:1.8.1.12) Gecko/20080201 Firefox/2.0.0.12',
    'Accept': 'text/xml,application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-gb,en;q=0.5',
    'Accept-Charset': 'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive'
}

req = urllib2.Request(url, opts, headers)
response = opener.open(req)
#something along these lines should work well for POSTing to a website
```

You can check out the documentation for urllib and urllib2 here:
http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html
http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html

Comment: Thanks randrumree for you input.

Comment: Thanks randrumree for you input. It seems like to me tht it will give me the stream of the data that we pass in the response right? something like if I send a URL http://www.google.co.in/search?q=test and it will return me the stream of data, offcourse with the header information as well then we need to parse that?

Comment: I'm not exactly completely sure; this is just what I used to post data to a form, or more specifically, a django modelform on one of my own sites. I think the header information is simply for validation by the website so whatever server, say apache or something, doesn't think the program you're running is some strange intruder.